# Issues in accessing values in nodejs passed from client side

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch

from client side I am passing this items array

```json
{ id: '1', quantity: '1' }
{ id: '2', quantity: '1' }
```

like shown below

```js
# Javascript
fetch("/purchase", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Accept: "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      items: items,
    }),
  })
```

In the server side I access the item.id which is passed from the client side and map the corresponding value in the storeItems array but here I am getting undefined.

```js
# Nodejs
const storeItems = new Map([
  [1, { price: 10000, name: "Assessment" }],
  [2, { price: 20000, name: "Therapy" }],
])


app.post("/purchase", (req, res) => { 

  
  req.body.items.forEach(function(item){
    console.log(item.id)  //this works   
    const storeItem = storeItems.get(item.id)
    console.log(storeItem)   //getting undefined
  })

})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `item.id` holds a string and passing e.g. "1" to the `get` method will result in `undefined` as the map's keys are of type `Number`. To fix this you can either convert the string to a number or store the item-ids as a string instead of a number:

```
const storeItem = storeItems.get(Number.parseInt(item.id));
```

OR

```
const storeItems = new Map([
  ["1", { price: 10000, name: "Assessment" }],
  ["2", { price: 20000, name: "Therapy" }],
])
```

Answer (score 2):

in your client side you are passing `id` of items as string

```
{ id: '1', quantity: '1' }
{ id: '2', quantity: '1' }
```

but in node.js map you define map as `integer`

```
const storeItems = new Map([
  [1, { price: 10000, name: "Assessment" }],
  [2, { price: 20000, name: "Therapy" }],
])
```

there are some solution ,
convert `id` to interger in

```
const storeItem = storeItems.get(item.id)
```

and convert `item.id` to Integer

```
const storeItem = storeItems.get(parseInt(item.id))
```

and final result of your node js will be like this :

```
# Nodejs
const storeItems = new Map([
  [1, { price: 10000, name: "Assessment" }],
  [2, { price: 20000, name: "Therapy" }],
])


app.post("/purchase", (req, res) => { 

  
  req.body.items.forEach(function(item){
    console.log(item.id)  //this works   
    const storeItem = storeItems.get(parseInt(item.id)) //// change this line
    console.log(storeItem)   //getting undefined
  })

})
```